# Removing unwanted text from nested list

Tags: python

I want to be able to remove some words that I don't want inside of my list.

code:

```
contour = cnt
stopwords = ['array', 'dtype=int32']

for word in list(contour):
    if word in stopwords:
        contour.remove(word)

print(contour)
```

output:

```
[array([[[21, 21]],

       [[21, 90]],

       [[90, 90]],

       [[90, 21]]], dtype=int32)]
```

`FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if word in stopwords:`

how do I remove `dtype=int32` and `array`, while making the list just a list of the two points?

ex:

```
[[21, 21],

 [21, 90],

 [90, 90],

 [90, 21]]
```

Comment: What is the type of this data structure `[array([[[21, 21]],

       [[21, 90]],

       [[90, 90]],

       [[90, 21]]], dtype=int32)]` ?

Comment: @balderman numpy array

Comment: Call `tolist()` in order to convert it to a python list. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.ndarray.tolist()`:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array(
    [np.array([[[21, 21]],

       [[21, 90]],

       [[90, 90]],

       [[90, 21]]], dtype="int32")]
)
l.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[[[21, 21]], [[21, 90]], [[90, 90]], [[90, 21]]]]
```